# Closures and reference setting

Tags: c#, reference, closures, variable-assignment

I think I have a fundamental misunderstanding here. Why does the test fail?

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
  public static Action To<T>(this T newValue, T oldValue) where T : class
  {
    return () => oldValue = newValue;            
  }
}

public static class Assign
{
  public static T TheValue<T>(T theValue)
  {
    return theValue;
  }
}

public class Tests 
{
  public void Test()
  {
    var a = new TestType { Name = "a" };
    var b = "b";
    Assign.TheValue(b).To(a.Name)();

    Assert.That(a.Name == "b"); //fails (a.Name == "a")
  }
}

public class TestType { public string Name {get;set;} }
```

Comment: Why would it become "b"? You're just passing a string-ref by value at various points.

Comment: My thinking was this: a ref to "b" (newValue) and a ref to "a" (oldValue) would be supplied to the method *To*, which would return a lambda for assigning newValue to OldValue. This lambda would be evaluated by the third set of parentheses on the line *Assign.TheValue(b).To(a.Name)();*. Clearly my understanding is totally wrong.

Comment: Think about what is a *variable*. "oldValue" is a *variable*. It has its *own* storage. It is not an alias for some other variable. The "ref" keyword *does* make an alias for a variable, and that is precisely why it is illegal to capture a ref variable in a closure; because *then you could capture a variable whose lifetime is shorter than the lifetime of the closure*.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Your comment helped the penny drop on this one. My comparative lack of experience with lambdas let me down here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It fails because the arguments to `To` are passed by value.

Just because `oldValue` is set to "b" doesn't mean that `a.Name` will be changed at all. In the call `To(a.Name)`, the expression `a.Name` is evaluated to a string reference, and that reference is passed to the method by value.

That's basic [parameter passing in C#](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html). Just using a closure doesn't change that.

What you *can* do is change the `To` method like this:

```
public static Action To<T>(this T newValue, Action<T> setter) where T : class
{
    return () => setter(newValue);
}
```

then change the call to:

```
Assign.TheValue(b).To(x => a.Name = x)();
```

Comment: I'm sure I'm being totally dumb, but I thought the evaluation of the lambda () => oldValue = newValue; would swap the reference to the old with the new value. I think I'm having a mental block here.

Comment: Suspect I need to re-read a chapter on parameter passing. Frankly this is embarrassing.

Answer (score 1):

Put another way,

```
var a = new TestType { Name = "a" };
Assign.TheValue(b).To(a.Name)();
```

is equivalent to

```
Assign.TheValue(b).To("a")();
```

just like

```
int x = 5;
Convert.ToDecimal(x);
```

is equivalent to

```
Convert.ToDecimal(5);
```